# connect to local AD domain controller

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory, ldap

I've set up a development server with AD and I'm trying to figure out how to connect to it via **.NET**. I'm working on the same machine that AD is installed on. I've gotten the DC name from AD, and the name of the machine, but the connection just does not work. I'm using the same credentials I used to connect to the server.

Any suggestions?

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://[dc.computername.com]", "administrator", "[adminpwd]");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you connect to the `RootDSE` container?

```
DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE", "administrator", "[adminpwd]");
```

If that works, you can then read out some of the properties stored in that root container

```
if (rootDSE != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine("RootDSE Properties:\n\n");

   foreach (string propName in rootDSE.Properties.PropertyNames)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("{0:-20d}: {1}", propName, rootDSE.Properties[propName][0]);
   }
}
```

This will show you some information about what LDAP paths are present in your installation.

Comment: stupid question here, but is RootDSE specific to my server? If so, how do I figure out what it is?

Comment: @user948060: `LDAP://RootDSE` is a well-known path that should be present in all Active Directory LDAP servers. The **contents** (the values in the properties) are of course specific to your setup - you should be seeing your default domain, LDAP paths etc.

Comment: Does that mean I should be able to navigate to LDAP://RootDSE via the web browser?

Comment: @user948060: never tried navigating there with a web browser.... try it! I don't know if it'll work - you'll need to use the code I showed in my response - that'll work for sure!

Comment: Yes, that did work, thanks! Now I've got to figure out which to use to view AD users...

Comment: @user948060: have a look at [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) - shows how to use the new `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace which is **really handy** for user and group management

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, using the `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` namespace :

```
//Define your connection
LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection("123.456.789.10:389");

try
{
      //Authenticate the username and password
      using (ldapConnection)
      {
          //Pass in the network creds, and the domain.
          var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password, Domain);
          //Since we're using unsecured port 389, set to false. If using port 636 over SSL, set this to true.
          ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = false;
          ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };
          //To force NTLM\Kerberos use AuthType.Negotiate, for non-TLS and unsecured, use AuthType.Basic
          ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
          ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);
      }
      catch (LdapException ldapException)
      {
          //Authentication failed, exception will dictate why
      }
}
```